# How to identify when yammer is making a request for a page

Tags: yammer

In our ASP.NET code we look at the user-agent to perform statistics.  Yes I know user-agent can be spoofed.

How can I identify when a web request for one of our pages comes from yammer?    It doesn't appear the user agent is set to yammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone tries to share a link on yammer,  the user agent that is set when the link is accessed is...

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Embedly/0.2; +http://support.embed.ly/)`